# PowerShell msiexec silent uninstall

Tags: powershell, variables, arguments, windows-installer

I'm attempting to uninstall a program "Global VPN Client" from over 150 computers, these computers have multiple versions with different identifying numbers. I'm try to perform this silently and with no reboot. So far here's my code:

```
$GUID = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | where name -Like "Global VPN Client" | select IdentifyingNumber

$Arguments = "/x" + $GUID + "/qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress"
 
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList $Arguments
```

The process starts however it doesn't perform this silently, my assumption is because the last line starts the "/x" and $GUID, this starting the uninstall before passing the last bit of the arguments.

Any advice or insight to get this working and have the wanted behavior?

Comment: You're not specifying the `/Uninstall` switch either.

Comment: `select -ExpandProperty IdentifyingNumber`

Answer (score 0):

First problem:

> ```
>  $GUID = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | where name -Like "Global VPN Client" | select IdentifyingNumber
> ```

The `Select-Object` (alias `select`) command outputs an object, so the GUID value actually is in `$GUID.IdentifyingNumber`. You could use it as such, but it would be conceptually clearer to assign the value of property `IdentifyingNumber` to `$GUID`:

```
$GUID = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | where name -Like "Global VPN Client" | select -Expand IdentifyingNumber

# alternative:
$GUID = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | where name -Like "Global VPN Client").IdentifyingNumber
```

There is another problem:

> ```
> $Arguments = "/x" + $GUID + "/qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress"
> ```

A space character is missing between `/x` and the `$GUID`. Either explicitly insert a space or let PowerShell do it automatically by passing an array of arguments:

```
$Arguments = "/x", $GUID, "/qn", "REBOOT=ReallySuppress"
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList $Arguments
```